# pre populationg password field zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

I have created a login form with a remember me checkbox. I have set cookie if the user checks the remember me link. I read the cookie the next time user opens the page. I am able to populate the username field but I'm unable to populate the password field. Is there any way to populate it?

Comment: with remember me you must autologin,, you must never want to fill in a password field. That can easily be read out to see what the password is.

Comment: Ditto @SynerCoder: Why do you want to show a login form when you remember the user with the cookie? The login credentials with the password you see on many web pages is coming from the password manager in the browser and not the webpage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set "true" to the propertie "renderPassword" like:

```
$password = new Zend_Form_Element_Password('senha');
$password->renderPassword = true;
$password->setValue("Senha");
```

Answer (score 3):

You should **never** pre-populate the password field. You would be taking the user's password and putting it in plain text in the value attribute of the element. Here is an example of [implementing remember me functionality in Zend Framework](http://www.phpriot.com/articles/zend-session/5). It may not be 100% current, but its a decent jumping off point.

Answer (score 0):

Although I would recommend against this but you can do this in the following way

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){$('#id_of_the_password_field').val('<?php echo $variable_containing_password;?>');});
 </script>
```